# lessphp compiles LESS CSS comments at one spot

Tags: css, less, lessphp

So when I compile my .less file can those comments be somehow skipped/removed? Because now it looks ridiculous. All the comments are mashed up at the top of the .css file.

I use Drupal 7, Bootstrap 3.0.0, LESS preprocessor module for D7 and lessphp library.

In the lessc.inc.php I find only one line with setPreserveComments:

```
public function setPreserveComments($preserve) {
    $this->preserveComments = $preserve;
}
```

It doesn't match the documentations at http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#preserving_comments

Comment: I guess you should use `$less->setPreserveComments(false);` before compiling to remove the comments and be sure the preservation of comments is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments should be [automatically removed](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#preserving_comments), however, if they're showing up, maybe the compiler is setting `setPreserveComments` to true, find it and comment it out.

Comment: Hi. Can you review the issue. I updated it with more infos. It doesn't let me add code to comments section here. Thanks.

Comment: That is the compiler code. Check if that function is being called somewhere and being set to true. If you find it, set it to `false`